# Unable to get any msgs/srvs to work in CMakeLists

Tags: ros2, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a controller node for a robot in ROS2 foxy and CMake is kicking my ass.
When I try to add a library none of the msgs/srvs work either my custom one or a built in such as std_msgs

Here is the type of error I get from the console, it's pretty much the same for all the msgs/srvs:

```
colcon build --packages-select legged_robot_controller
Starting >>> legged_robot_controller
--- stderr: legged_robot_controller                             
In file included from /home/robdome/ros2_ws/src/legged_robot_controller/src/control.cpp:31:
/home/robdome/ros2_ws/src/legged_robot_controller/include/legged_robot_controller/control.hpp:38:10: fatal error: std_srvs/srv/Empty.hpp: No such file or directory
   38 | #include <std_srvs/srv/Empty.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/control.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/control.dir/src/control.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:107: CMakeFiles/control.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< legged_robot_controller [5.58s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [6.01s]
  1 package failed: legged_robot_controller
  1 package had stderr output: legged_robot_controller
```

Here is my CMakeLists:

```
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_srvs REQUIRED)
find_package(nav_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(legged_robot_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(dynamixel_sdk REQUIRED)

add_library( control src/control.cpp )
ament_target_dependencies( control
        rclcpp
        tf2_ros
        std_srvs
        std_msgs
        geometry_msgs
        nav_msgs
        sensor_msgs
        legged_robot_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
        )

include_directories(
        include/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        )

ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_dependencies(rclcpp geometry_msgs sensor_msgs std_srvs std_msgs legged_robot_msgs 

tf2_ros)

ament_package()
```

I've spent that last day or so trying to figure it out on my own to no avail, I apologize if I'm doing something stupid I'm new to ROS and don't have a whole lot of C++ experience.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364484/unable-to-get-any-msgs/srvs-to-work-in-cmakelists/) by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2020-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS2's rclcpp, the names of the header files for message, service, and action definitions are lowercase separated by underscores. For Empty.srv, try including it using:

```
#include <std_srvs/srv/empty.hpp>
```

---

Originally posted by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) with karma: 340 on 2020-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) on 2020-11-01**:
thanks schornak, that did it now I just need to figure out why my custom msgs aren't generating a .hpp
EDIT: they are being generated I'm guessing I need to point CMake to the install folder?

**Comment by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) on 2020-11-02**:
I'd suggest posting a new question with some details (CMakeLists.txt, etc.) about the package where your custom msgs are defined and generated.

**Comment by [lutinplunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/62191/lutinplunder/) on 2020-11-02**:
I figured it out, my cmake was fine my includes were pointing to the actual msg name not the name of the generated .hpp. I figured I'd just add that here for continuity.